# Simple Upload PHP form trouble

Tags: php, pdf

Hi Im trying to create a simple Upload php form however I when I upload the pdf I get an error message on line 8, here is my code;

(Code updated)

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
       $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
       $file_size =$_FILES['uploadFile']['size'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
       $file_type=$_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];   
       $value = explode(".", $file_name);
       $file_ext = strtolower(array_pop($value));

      $expensions= array("pdf");   
      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)== false)
      {
       $errors="Extension not allowed, please choose a PDF file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 9097152)
      {
      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }    
      if(empty($errors)==true)
      {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"client_files/bond/uploads/".$file_name);
//include here insert query**
 echo "The file ".$file_name." has been uploaded.";
       //echo "Success";
      }
      else
      {
       print_r($errors);
      }
     }
    ?>
```

And in my html file the body consists of a simple form;

```
  <div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div>Logo<span>Here</span></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="login">
                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Please choose a file: <input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and where did you defined `$pdf`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function Output() on a non-object in /public_html/bond/upload.php on line 8 and I feel its the reason $pdf isnt defined what would I need to add to the pdf to define it?

Comment: You have to initialize `$pdf`! Because `$pdf` is not an object. So make a object from your class!

Comment: Sorry where would I need to do this and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this
<div class="body"></div>
        <div class="grad"></div>
        <div class="header">
            <div>Logo<span>Here</span></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="login">
                <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Please choose a file: <input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `$uploadFile_size` variable in the file. This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try it
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
       $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
       $file_size =$_FILES['uploadFile']['size'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
       $file_type=$_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];   
       $value = explode(".", $file_name);
       $file_ext = strtolower(array_pop($value));
       //$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode(".",$file_name))); -->this line wnt work bcoz only variable should be passed inside explode

      $expensions= array("pdf");   
      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)== false)
      {
       $errors="Extension not allowed, please choose a PDF file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152)
      {
      $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }    
      if(empty($errors)==true)
      {
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

 echo "The file ".$file_name." has been uploaded.";
       //echo "Success";
      }
      else
      {
       print_r($errors);
      }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have added it to the server and replaced it with the old php code however it still isn't uploading the pdf or showing any error messages now?

Comment: ? Im loading the php onto the server it does the whole upload ..% but then when its complete it goes blank and doesn't upload the pdf to the server?

Comment: check your folder name and path.i don't know what type of error you geting

Comment: they are all correct and the same on the server what do you mean by //include here insert query** in the code?

Comment: now i sent to  you code.You didn't give in form name="submit" so it's not working,i think so now it'll work

Answer (score 0):

String Strtolower($string) Is the prototype.